# Use a custom file other than `bower.json` to install dependencies

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, bower-install

How can I tell **bower** to install my dependencies from a custom file (say `my-custom-deps.json`)?

```
dir/
  --bower.json
  --my-custom-deps.json
  //other files and folders
```

There is no command like `bower install --use-file my-custom-deps.json` right?

**Why?**

I want to build the app with:

1. An older version of a dependency
2. Latest version of that dependency

in my `gulp` task.